# Why is this question closed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

[What is wrong with this item stats?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80732/what-is-wrong-with-this-item-stats)

What I asked is quite clear. Why the left item has lower Damage than the right. I also have a good answer.

Namely that the 40% damage is already incorporated.

It's something not obvious.

So why it's a bad question?

The question clearly stated that I ask why the DAMAGE is lower on the left. I mention nothing about valuation.

Comment: How in the earth the amount of damage if I use the left spears is lower? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: The picture tooltip says so. Damage is lower by 34 if I use the left spear even though the left spear has higher intelligent bonus and 40% damage stats

Comment: *Minimum* damage is "lower by 34." Maximum damage has a gap of **201**. Your average damage is between the minimum and maximum, not on either extreme. I haven't played D3 in a while, but primary stats are worth *much* less to DPS than weapon damage. Also, I don't believe the 45% damage is "already incorporated," unless you mean on the big **634.6** value.

Comment: @Koviko Affixes on the weapon itself *are* computed in the displayed Weapon DPS listing, per LessPop_MoreFizz's answer [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/69727/7428).

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh Yup, lack of research effort. :)

Comment: Edit your question to make it less unclear and it can be re-opened :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify, your question was vague. You mentioned prices and then, rather cryptically, mentioned damage.

We didn't assume you were asking why you'd lose DPS with the new weapon because, on the weapon, it says that the DPS is lower. 634.6 is less than 661.8. 197 max damage is less than 393 max damage. The 45% damage [is explained in other questions, here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/69727/7428).

If your question was about the price, then it isn't a question that we can answer and it's not constructive. If your question is about why one number is lower than another number, then your question is not useful and shows very, *very* little research effort.

Comment: understood okay

Answer (score 5):

The fact that you got not just one, but two answers and several comments about valuation tells me that *yes, your question was really unclear.*

I'd suggest editing it.